# JPA Repository: GetMapping with 2 Params but both params are optional to key in

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Based on my question above, I have a table named User. I want to display all the data based on two parameters, **status** and **createdBy**. For example, if the user key is in both params, it will show based on both params. If the user just want to key in **status** = 1 and the **createdBy** remains empty, the data will show only with status = 1. The same goes for when the user only wants to key in **createdBy**. If the user does not key in both param, it will display all data.

Now. I only can do this if the user key in both param. Below is my code:

**User.java**

```
        @Table(name = "idr_user")
        public class User {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;
            private String name;
            private String email;
            private int status;
            @Column(name="factory_id", nullable = true)
            private int factoryId;
            @Column(name="created_by", nullable = true)
            private Integer createdBy;
            @Column(name="role_id", nullable = true)
            private Integer roleId;
            
        }
```

**UserResponseDto.java**

```
        public class UserResponseDto {
            private int id;
            private String name;
            private String email;
            private Integer factoryId;
            private Integer status;
            private Integer createdBy;
            private Integer roleId;
        }
```

**UserRepository**

```
     @Repository
     public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

        public List<User> findAllUserByStatusAndCreatedBy(Optional<Integer> status, Optional<Integer> createdBy);
     }
```

**UserController**

```
        public class UserController {

            @Autowired
            private UserService userService;

            @Autowired
            private ModelMapper modelMapper;

            @GetMapping(path="user/statusAndCreatedBy/{status}/{createdBy}")
            public @ResponseBody Iterable<UserResponseDto> getUserByStatusAndCreatedBy(@PathVariable Optional<Integer> status, @PathVariable Optional<Integer> createdBy) {
                return userService.getUserByStatusAndCreatedBy(status, createdBy).stream().map(user -> modelMapper.map(user, UserResponseDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

        }
```

**UserService.java**

```
        public class UserService {
            @Autowired
            private UserRepository userRepository;

            public List<User> getUserByStatusAndCreatedBy(Optional<Integer> status, Optional<Integer> createdBy) {
                return userRepository.findAllUserByStatusAndCreatedBy(status, createdBy);
            }

        }
```

Hence, anyone can help? Im stuck at this. Thank you

Comment: why don't you use predicate?

Comment: @bananas can show me the code? or amend my code above?

Comment: No, I will not. Not my job

Comment: @bananas wow !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA specifications for optional parameter filtering

Example:

```
userRepository.findAll(isStatus(status).and(isCreatedBy(createdBy)));
```

Here, create `isStatus()` and `isCreatedBy()` function using specification.

Read here for how to write specification : https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/using-jpa-specifications-with-kotlin/

Comment: can you help me to write the full code or amend my code?